# Form not loading for all users - Access 2016

Tags: forms, ms-access

I built a simple ticket submission app in Access 2016. The database is split with the back end on a network drive accessible by all users and the .accde front end saved directly to all users' desktops. For about half of my users, only the header of the form partially loads like in the image below, regardless if they're in read-only or not. All of them have identical settings in the trust center.

[image: Blank Form]
[Full Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKSIV.jpg)

Comment: Cross-posted https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=300933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the title bar `AppData\Local\...\Content.Outlook\...`, the frontend has been opened directly from an Outlook attachment.

These are always read-only.

Tell your users to save the attachment to a folder, and start it from there.

Or set up a better way to distribute the frontend to users than E-Mail attachments.

// Edit: If they **don't** get the yellow bar, but still can't enter data in the form, then they probably don't have write access to the backend folder.

Comment: This ended up being it. The permissions were completely screwed up for the backend folder and we had no idea. Spending the rest of the day looking at that because there's no rhyme or reason to these.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have clicked on the app twice so have opened two copies of it.
As the first is already open, the lock file will prevent the second copy opening correctly.
Look for two icons on the taskbar or two instances of Access in Task Manager.

Comment: Same screen appears when opening from the local desktop off a restart, with only one instance running.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to distribute the frontend to a dedicated subfolder of *%localappdata%*.

What you need is:

- a folder path where the user has full rights
- to set some security settings in the Registry
- a script to copy your application file and create Desktop shortcut

It is described in full in my article here:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html)

which also contains a *script* that carries out these tasks:

- creates subfolders in the user's LocalAppData  folder
- kills the application should it be running
- copies the current version of the application to the local folder
- copies a second copy (launched by the first for background tasks)
- creates/copies a shortcut
- writes the security settings for the application in the Registry
- launches the application (which then launches the background application)